# gzip with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, gzip

Is there anyway to gzip with codeigniter? If yes please share Library, plugin or helper...
Thankyou!

Comment: I think it's better if you explore the link mentioned below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855966/codeigniter-gzip-compression-issue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your config file change `compress_output` to `TRUE`. I think it uses gzip.

There's also this disclaimer:

> VERY IMPORTANT:
>       If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it means
>   you are prematurely outputting
>   something to your browser. It could
>   even be a line of whitespace at the
>   end of one of your scripts. For
>   compression to work, nothing can be
>   sent before the output buffer is
>   called by the output class. Do not
>   "echo" any values with compression
>   enabled.

Comment: Good answer. Also note that on shared hosts, it could be that the virtual host setup already has gzip enabled on all content. If you then enable gzip in CI, you get double compression, which leads to very strange issues :)

Comment: @Matthew: i do the gzip enable but according the codeigniter documentation **Do not "echo" any values with compression enabled** . how can i use ajax in my site . because it use the echo to return value...

Comment: @Hameed, I haven't had to deal with that (I only use server side compression). But maybe this function will help: $this->output->set_output($data);

Comment: public function __construct()
 {
        parent::__construct();
     ob_flush();
     ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my [site](https://www.rishtasonline.com/), but now I've figured it out by applying these steps:

1. Go to CI's *config.php*:
2. Find this code: `$config['compress_output']`
3. Change value from `FALSE` to `TRUE`:

`$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;`

Now you have to enable `"zlib.output_compression"` from your server's `php.ini`. You will not receive error on your front-end.