# CodeIgniter GZIP compression issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, gzip

I am developing a website using CodeIgniter HMVC.

1. I have enabled GZIP Compression in server(cPanel).
2. I have enabled compression in CodeIgniter Config( `$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;` )
3. I have added `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` at top of the `index.php` file.
4. I have added DEFLATE in `.htaccess` file.

When I test the root domain(https://seocompany.us.com/) is GZIP compressed.

But when I test any other pages(https://seocompany.us.com/services), error shows GZIP is not enabled.

Comment: You dont need to do steps 2 and 3, you can do it all in htaccess

Comment: Hi Brad, I tried all these multiple times but never worked. GZIP enabling on cpanel works in another server, but not in my current server.

Answer (score 3):

If you did it in cPanel thats probably enough.

Or you canJust do this in htaccess

```
# Force compression for mangled headers.
# http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
# (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
#  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
#  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/ld+json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Brad, I tried all these multiple times but never worked. GZIP enabling on cpanel works in another server, but not in my current server.

Comment: Hi @brad Thanks for the help, I implemented your solution but it returns the same result. I have added screenshot for your reference http://prntscr.com/eltm4x

Comment: Sorry I couldnt be of help.

Comment: try this public function __construct()
 {
        parent::__construct();
     ob_flush();
     ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    }